# Supervisor как перезапустить

Tags: supervisord

Подскажите плз, как после изменения supervisors.conf применить изменения в силу? 
И как можно сделать, что6ы запускался после включения ОС? Например если сервер перезапустить.
У меня centos 7

Comment: Никто не знает?

Comment: Прочитать обновлённый конфиг — supervisorctl update. Запуск после включения к ОС — добавление службы в автозагрузку по инструкции к вашей ОС.